# Catch exception on variable declaration

Tags: c++, exception

I have a style issue in my code that I wonder if others have encountered.
Say I have a class that either doesnt have a default constructor, or has a default constructor that I don't want to call (for performance and style reason). For sake of example, let's say this is a File object.

Now let's say that I have a file that contains a list of filenames to delete... And I want to do the following:

```
File f("foo");
for (const string& filenameToDelete : f.Lines())
    File(filenameToDelete).Delete();
```

File can throw FileNotFound in the constructor or in the Delete function. My code must throw on first failure to delete a file, but must not throw if the file "foo" doesnt exist (the absence of the file just means that there is nothing to delete).

I wish I could write something like this:

```
try { File f("foo"); } catch (FileNotFound) { return; }
for (const string& filenameToDelete : f.Lines())
    File(filenameToDelete).Delete();
```

but that obviously doesn't compile.
I could do this:

```
unique_ptr<File> f;
try { f.reset(new File("foo")); } catch (FileNotFound) { return; }
for (const string& filenameToDelete : f->Lines())
    File(filenameToDelete).Delete();
```

but I somewhat dislike the fact that I need to do a memory allocation for a variable that could otherwise be stack allocated...

If I want to write the code with the somewhat arbitrary constraint that I don't do heap allocations, I can only think of doing it this way:

```
struct FileNotFoundToRethrow : public FileNotFound {};
try
{
    File f("foo");
    try
    {
        for (const string& filenameToDelete : f.Lines())
            File(filenameToDelete).Delete();
    }
    catch (FileNotFound)
    {
        throw FileNotFoundToRethrow();
    }
}
catch (FileNotFoundToRethrow) { throw; }
catch (FileNotFound) { return; }
```

I find this pretty ugly, it's hard to see that all I want to do is handle the FileNotFound exception thrown on the first line... Any better way?

Comment: Why do you insist on writing `File(filenameToDelete).Delete()` as a single statement? If you split that up into `File foo(filenameToDelete)` and then `foo.Delete()`, it seems like you'd be able to do what you want.

Comment: I was writing them as a single statement mostly to make the example as short as possible (to save time to the reader). I'm not sure I see how splitting the line in two would help in my case.

Comment: _Boost.Optional_ would work just like `unique_ptr`, except no allocations are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it with a flag

```
bool throwOnNotFound = false;

try
{
    File f("foo");

    throwOnNotFound = true;

    for (const string& filenameToDelete : f.Lines())
        File(filenameToDelete).Delete();
}
catch (FileNotFound)
{
    if (throwOnNotFound)
        throw;
}
```

Comment: You are right that it's cleaner than my definition of a new exception type! I still kind of dislike the fact that the catch block is that far from the line for which we want to handle the exception...

Answer (score 1):

There is maybe a way for all those who feel particularly smarty, [extending the lifetime with reference to const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/). But there are drawbacks. A class must have a null (or default) object, and, well, the reference is *const*.

```
File fooFile()
{
    try { return File("foo"); } catch (FileNotFound) { return File::Default; }
}
```

using it:

```
const File& foo = fooFile();

if (foo.IsDefault())
    return;

for (const string& filenameToDelete : f.Lines())
        File(filenameToDelete).Delete();
```